# What protocol should I prefer for Single Sign-On - OAuth 2.1, OpenID Connect, SAML or some other. Which 1 is more safe?

Tags: oauth, single-sign-on, openid-connect, saml

One of my juniors asked me this question.

I went through all these protocols and related documentation but couldn't figure out which one to prefer.

Answer (score 2):

More safe?
Most of the protocols are "safe" when properly implemented.

Most security failures have more to do with implementation than they do with protocol failures.

Comment: agree! But if you have to choose among them, what would be your preference?

Comment: Personally, I am a standards guy and the OAuth/OpenID Connect/WebAuthn are my choices.
I worked with proprietary solutions for many years and still have nightmares.
And what @Gary Archer Said.

Answer (score 2):

The moving parts work like this these days. in an optimal architecture:

- UI clients use OpenID Connect to sign users in. This involves opening a browser at a request URL that hands control over to an Authorization Server (AS).
- The AS can manage authenticating users in various ways. The AS then issues tokens to the client, including an access token for sending to APIs.
- APIs do OAuth work to verify a JWT access token on every request, then trust the scopes and claims in the payload, and use them to authorize access to data.

OAuth and OpenID Connect give you this end-to-end capability that works in all types of app. They are used together and preferred over SAML these days, which was used in websites, before people used APIs.

Comment: In that matter, preference goes to OAuth2.1

Comment: That's really just updated best practices, but yes, definitely worth following.

Answer (score 2):

They are both safe.

SAML is older and is more for legacy corporate applications.

SAML does not cater for REST API and is not recommended for mobile or SPA applications.

Comment: Legacy corporate applications as in old or outdated systems which have limited support for changes/adapting new technologies. Do you think we should use OAuth or OIDC for newer applications?

Comment: OIDC is a layer on top of OAuth that standardizes authentication. So going OIDC makes sense.